# JobCancellationException: MonoCoroutines was cancelled

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I encountered an issue when using the Spring Boot reactive WebClient/Kotlin Coroutines to send request in a `forEach` loop.

```kotlin
webClient.post()
   .uri(url)
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .bodyValue(body)
   .awaitExchange { ...}
```

But it is finally stopped due to a wired exception similar to this in the middle way(some requests are successful):

```bash
~.client.ExchangeFunctions: Cancel signal (to close connection)
...
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellactionException: MonoCoroutines was cancelled.
...
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellactionException: MonoCoroutines was cancelled.
...
```

And the last exception `JobCancellactionException` is thrown again and again till time out.

The `awaitExchange` internally called `MonoCoroutines`.

What we want is if there is an exception in one iteration, mark it as failure and skip it(**we have used try/catch to wrap http calling**), and move to the next iteration.

Now the result is it stopped all of the left requests.

**How to handle this exception gracefully**? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably post more of your code, but I'm guessing you need `supervisorScope`, and something like `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO)` if it's from a scheduled thread.

Comment: The scheduled tasks is run by AWS lambda to call API, so you can ignore the scheduled tasks here.

Comment: i have also a lot of exceptions "MonoCoroutine was cancelled" in webflux application

Comment: @rsobies In my project, most of the exception is raised by connection issues, but it blocked the client and never stopped.